# how to pass a table as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: teradata

Is something like that possible in teradata?

```
create procedure my_proc(in table_param table)
begin
    insert into table1
    select *
    from table_param;
end;
```

I believe it is possible in T-SQL

Comment: You can pass the _name_ of a table as a character string and use that to construct and execute dynamic SQL (such as . You can't pass the table itself as a parameter.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, I used that work around. Also creating global temporary table for a procedure if i want strict data structure.